# mod_security2.so: undefined symbol: ap_unixd_set_gl

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-security

```
service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 205 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_security2.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_security2.so: undefined symbol: ap_unixd_set_global_mutex_perms
                                                           [FAILED]
```

my httpd file:

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadFile /usr/lib/libxml2.so
#LoadFile /usr/lib/liblua5.1.so
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
```

any ideas? google has nothing.

I followed these guidelines:
https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#wiki-SVN_Access

Apache is 2.2.15
PHP is 5.3.3

I installed apache/php via yum

Comment: Errors like that usually mean you somehow built it for the wrong version of apache. Do you have more than one apache installed? If you have `httpd` installed through yum, why didn't you install `mod_security` through yum too?  Which distribution are you using?

Comment: CentOS. I was trying to learn how to manually install mod_security. So if I do from source I need to do source as well from apache?

Comment: No, you don't need to build Apache from source, but you will need the httpd-devel packages so you can build mod_security against it. BUT, presumably would get matching mod_security from EPEL

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have multiple version of httpd installed on machine. You can solve this by using

```
./configure --with-apxs=/path/to/httpd-2.x.y/bin/apxs
```

Comment: No, it is not working